# Inconsistent transition speed when div heights are different

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I’m trying to create this animation where you reveal a different paragraph when clicked on a button.
But it seems like the transition speed can vary even if the duration is the same for both elements because the paragraphs can be either longer or shorter obviously. In the screen recordings below, you can see what I want to do.

So if I want the transition speed to be the same, should I need a jquery/JS script to get the longer paragraph's parent div height and apply it to the other div?
Or is there any other ways to make the transition speed the same?

Inconsistent speed when paragraph wrappers have different heights
https://s3.tenten.co/share/Screen-Recording-2021-08-06-at-18.59.01.mov

Consistent speed when paragraph wrappers have the same height
https://s3.tenten.co/share/Screen-Recording-2021-08-06-at-18.59.54.mov

ps: I'm building it on webflow (visual dev tool) so I don't exactly have the full access to the code of the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation speed is usually set as a time interval in seconds, meaning that it will perform the animation in 2 seconds for example and set the movement speed according to the height in order to finish the transition in specified time, resulting in the behavior you're experiencing. Therefore as you said, the solution is to get the div height and apply it to the other div in order to get identical transition speeds. you can use jQuery's height() function to do that ([this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_height.asp) is a small explanation on it just in case it was needed). Then you just modify the other divs' heights also using JS.